# Is there any API for video conferencing for Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, api, web-deployment, flutter-web, video-conferencing

I am currently working on Flutter web and want to build Google meet like feature in the web app. I found some like Jitsi, 100ms and VideoSDK, but they don't support FLutter web.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with it. But i know Agora is supporting flutter. But i don't know if it will work with flutter web.

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/landing-page?platform=Flutter

Edit:
The SDK package says it supports web
https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/versions/5.2.0